# AutoGenerateColumns Property in GridView

Tags: asp.net

Would like know how does **AutoGenerateColumns** Property works in the background for GridView. Suppose if we want to Assign the **HeaderText** property of **TemplateField** in the GridView to the column names from the assigned **DataSource** property of the GridView using **InlineExpression <%# %>**. How to do it.

Example:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="TempGridView" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
 <Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="{Inline Expression to Get column Name from DataSource}"> 
</asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

AutoGenerateColumns will just look up all the public properties of the entity you have in the DataSource and it will use the property name as the HeaderText and values on the items.

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                HeaderTextForName
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Name")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: How will we do that using the Inline Expression after setting AutoGenerateColums property to false.

Comment: Is it not enough to have the HeaderText property in the TemplateField, do you need it localized or what?

Comment: Need to know how to retrieve the Column name from the datasource to HeaderText property of TemplateField using Inline Expression.

Comment: Why do you need to get the column name from the datasource, just name it what ever you want? Or if grid is supposed to be dynamic then dont use templates and create classes with required public properties for UI to bind to.

Comment: leaning how to do it using Inline Expression

Comment: Perhaps, say want to set few TemplateField column with custom name as you said and for other TemplateField need to set the same name as DataSource table column name.